# Combobox doesn't show correctly with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zk

I want to make a form containing a combobox [ZK component] with Bootstrap but the combobox is appearing with problem : 
[image]

**-->** Here's a [zkFiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/af6lv3/5-Another-new-ZK-fiddle) to reproduce the problem.

**Environnement:**

- ZK v6.5.1
- Bootstrap v3

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ZK is building its own HTML layout for components.

For the combobox, it wraps the `<input>` element in a `<span>` element.

So when you apply the Bootstrap `form-control` class to the ZK combobox, it does not apply to the `<input>` element but to the wrapper `<span>` element, it is why you are seeing your combobox inside a Bootstrap `form-control` styled element.

You can just remove the class applied to the combobox (`sclass="form-control"`). And if you really want the `form-control` Bootstrap style, then apply/override the corresponding CSS directly on the `z-combobox` and `z-combobox-input` ZK CSS classes.